# How to center the contents of the web page inside the body tag using CSS or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I know this sounds odd but I met this problem in which I cannot center the elements inside the `<body>` tag. I already used `margin: 0px auto;` but still nothing works. Is there a way I can make it by using jquery? Thanks

This is my code in my .css file

```
body {
margin: 0px auto !important;
background:#FFFFFF;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: We're going to have to see some more code.

Comment: Can you show us an example that what you want to do?

Comment: You could paste part of the code or try to recreate the problem at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Niklas links can go stale it's always best for the code to posted directly here.

Comment: Uhm, there's something that bothers me though, when I used firebug and excluded the styles in my body, there are styles that occur, it came from a file called html.css and it's from the system. Is this a big deal?

Comment: You'll need to set a width on the item if you want to use `margin: 0px auto`.

Comment: @Marrowmaw Of course, but it's a pretty common way to handle a problem on SO these days. Solve the issue at jsfiddle then post the solution here, both the code and the link to an example. Like **A.K** is doing.

Comment: @CHi RiLo: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Setting auto margin works, but it needs a fixed on that element in order to work.

```css
<your-element>{
   width:200px;
   margin:0 auto;    
}​
```

If you want to center several elements you can either set width and margin on all of those, or cleaner - introduce a wrapper element which holds all your elements you want to center and declare the width and margin on that element. This has the advantage that you only need to declare the width once, making it easier to change it later.

Answer (score 1):

Set `margin: 0px auto;` on the element which you want to make center.

Example:

```
  body{
      width: 100%;
  }

  .aDiv {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/3AFyn/)

**Edited:**

As OP stated in his comments, that;

> He want to center all the elements inside the body.

So I suggest to set `margin: 0px auto;` on all element which you want to make center.

[**SEE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/TMTWJ/)

Comment: in my case, i want to center all the elements inside the body. will that be okay?

Comment: You need to set `margin: 0px auto;` on all elements

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to centre the contents simply using the CSS:

```
 body{text-align:center;}
```

but if you've already done that with no effect try using padding on either side of the child elements, so they are positioned in the centre.

```
 body{text-align:center; padding-left:20%; padding-right:20%;}
```

If you're still having problems, make sure that the elements you are trying to centre aren't set to position:relative; or position:absolute;

Comment: It's not stupid, sometimes when browsers or sections of code don't play ball, you have to improvise ;)

Comment: I'm not saying you're stupid ;) When your code/markup doesn't play ball you're playing it wrong.

Comment: Quite probably haha, but then CHi RiLo says margin: 0px auto doesn't work lol, so who knows how he's playing!

Answer (score 0):

You may make a div inside your parent `<body>`, give it a specific width, and then centre it by giving auto left and right margins.

for example;

```
.test{
    background: #06C;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 80%; /* or you may give it in px like 100px */
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5GSw/)*** is the live demo

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple.

```
body {
 text-align:center; /* ie */}
div#website_container {
 width:960px;
 margin:0 auto; /* others */
 text-align:left;}
```

Then start creating your site within the div `website_container`.